# Are computed observables on prototypes feasible in KnockoutJS?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have an array of items coming back from the service. I'm trying to define a computed observable for every Item instance, so my instinct tells me to put it on the prototype.

One case for the computed observable: the system calculates points, but the user can choose to override the calculated value. I need to keep the calculated value available in case the user removes the override. I also need to coalesce user-assigned and calculated points, and add up the totals.

I'm using mapping to do the following:

```
var itemsViewModel;
var items = [
    { 'PointsCalculated' : 5.1 },
    { 'PointsCalculated' : 2.37, 'PointsFromUser' : 3 }
];

var mapping = {
    'Items' : {
        create : function(options) {
            return new Item(options.data);
        }
    }
};

var Item = function(data) {
    var item = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, item);
};

Item.prototype.Points = function () {
    var item = this;
    return ko.computed(function () {
        // PointsFromUser may be 0, so only ignore it if the value is undefined/null
        return (item.PointsFromUser != null) ? item.PointsFromUser : item.PointsCalculated;
    });
};

ko.mapping.fromJS(items, mapping, itemsViewModel);
```

The way it works now, I have to call the anonymous function to return the computed observable. That appears to create a new instance of the computed observable for each binding, which defeats most of the point of putting it on the prototype. And it's a little annoying having to decipher how many parentheses to use each time I access an observable.

It's also somewhat fragile. If I attempt to access Points() in code, I can't do

```
var points = 0;
var p = item.Points;
if (p && typeof p === 'function') {
    points += p();
}
```

because that changes to context of Points() to DOMWindow, instead of item.

If I put the computed in create() in the mapping, I could capture the context, but then there's a copy of the method on each object instance.

I've found Michael Best's Google Groups post (http://groups.google.com/group/knockoutjs/browse_thread/thread/8de9013fb7635b13). The prototype returns a new computed observable on "activate". I haven't figured out what calls "activate" (maybe Objs?), but I'm guessing it still happens once per object, and I haven't a clue what scope 'this' will get.

At this point, I believe I'm past what's available in published docs, but I'm still working up to deciphering what's going on from the source.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mention that you don't want to have an instance of the `ko.computed` function on each instance of your javascript class, however, that won't really work with how ko's functionality has been built. When you use `ko.computed` or `ko.observable` they create specific memory pointers to private variables inside that you would not normally want to be shared across class instances (although in rare cases you might).

I do something like this:

```
var Base = function(){
    var extenders = [];

    this.extend = function(extender){
        extenders.push(extender);
    };

    this.init = function(){
        var self = this; // capture the class that inherits off of the 'Base' class

        ko.utils.arrayForEach(extenders, function(extender){

             // call each extender with the correct context to ensure all
             // inheriting classes have the same functionality added by the extender
             extender.call( self );
        });
    };
};

var MyInheritedClass = function(){
    // whatever functionality you need

   this.init(); // make sure this gets called
};

// add the custom base class
MyInheritedClass.prototype = new Base();
```

then for the computed observables (which HAVE to be instance functions on each instance of your `MyInheritedClass`) I just declare them in an `extender` like so:

```
MyInheritedClass.prototype.extend(function(){

     // custom functionality that i want for each class 
     this.something = ko.computed(function() {
         return 'test';
     });
});
```

Given your example and the `Base` class defined above, you could easily do:

```
var Item = function(data) {
    var item = this;

    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, item);

    this.init(); // make sure this gets called
};
Item.prototype = new Base();

Item.prototype.extend(function () {
    var self = this;

    this.Points = ko.computed(function () {

        // PointsFromUser may be 0, so only ignore it if the value is undefined/null
        return (self.PointsFromUser != null) ? 
               self.PointsFromUser : self.PointsCalculated;
    });
};
```

Then all instances of your `Item` class will have a `Points` property, and it will correctly handle the `ko.computed` logic per instance.

Comment: Thanks. I think the purpose of .extend() just clicked.This solves my scoping / double function invocation problems nicely, and I'll take your word that Knockout won't let me keep the actual computed observable on the prototype.

Comment: eric, could you provide a more "sugarified" version? Something like childClass = BaseClass.extend(function(){/*...*/}) that already does the prototype chain setup? Having to do it manually for each class instance is a bit weird...

Comment: I don't see any reason why you couldn't put an 'extend' static function on the inherited Constructor, as long as it basically does:
`SubClass.extend = function(extender){ SubClass.prototype.extend(extender); 
};`

Answer (score 0):

```
Item.prototype.Points = function () {
var item = this;
return ko.computed(function () {
    // PointsFromUser may be 0, so only ignore it if the value is undefined/null
    return (item.PointsFromUser != null) ? item.PointsFromUser : item.PointsCalculated;
});
```

};

Answer (score 0):

```
Item.prototype.extend(function () {
var scope = this
this.Points = ko.computed(function () {
    return (this.PointsFromUser != null) ? 
           this.PointsFromUser : this.PointsCalculated;
}, scope);
};
```