# Is it possible to toggle a components template with the params object in the binding

Tags: knockout.js, web-component

From the documentation I've read it doesn't seem like it is possible to determine which template to show based off of a parameter passed into the view model. I'm also not convinced this is a good idea just wanted to know if it was possible.

Here is a fiddle of my current solution: http://jsbin.com/fefagopajo/4/edit?html,output

The issue is having to have a basically master component that sets up the rest of the other components based on if it's readonly. This could be done in js in a config step but I just want to know if there is a clear or best practice around this.

Because JSBin is complicated apparently.

JS:

```
var readOnlyLoader = {
    getConfig: function (name, callback) {
        callback({ template: { element: name + "-readonly" } });
    }
};

ko.components.register("all-component", {
  viewModel: function(p){
    console.log(p.readonly);
    if(p.readonly){
       ko.components.loaders.unshift(readOnlyLoader);
    }

   return p.data;
 },
template : { element : "all-template" }
});

ko.components.register("text-editor-component", {
    viewModel: function (params) {

        this.content = params.content;
            console.log(this.readonly);
      //if readonly, use a different template

    },
    template: { element: "text-editor-template" }
});

ko.applyBindings({
 text: ko.observable("test")
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type='text' data-bind='value: text'/>
<all-component params="data: $data, readonly: true"></all-component>

<template id='all-template'>
 <text-editor-component params='content: text'></text-editor-component>
</template>

<template id='text-editor-template'>
 <input type='text'data-bind='value: content'/>
</template>
<template id='text-editor-component-readonly'>
 <span data-bind='text: content'></span>
</template>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you have tried and perhaps include some code or a fiddle?

Comment: Please post your code in the question itself.

Comment: You could always have the template in the component be `<div data-bind="template: {name: $data.name }"></div>`.  It's a template inside a template !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are computed observables on prototypes feasible in KnockoutJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299919/are-computed-observables-on-prototypes-feasible-in-knockoutjs)